# Error when generating a spell file in Vim: E484: Can't open file/tmp/tr.utf-8.spl

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I try to generate Turkish spell file for Vim from a word list with the following command:

```
mksp /tmp tr_TR.words
```

`tr_TR.words` resides in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vim72`

Vim starts reading the word file but the process is interrupted before completion. Vim gives the following error message:

```
Compressed 5110514 of 6389213 nodes; 1278699 (20%) remaining
Writing spell file /tmp/tr.utf-8.spl ...
E484: Can't open file/tmp/tr.utf-8.spl
```

I use Gvim 7.2 on Win 7. The word list file `tr_TR.words` contains lines of words such as:

```
aba
abaca
abacası
abacı
```

I couldn't find the cause of this error on internet. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are on windows, you should know, there is no `/tmp` directory. So try:

```
mksp YOUR_INPUT_FILE_PATH\FILENAME C:\tmp\tr_TR.words
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `/tmp` in the command with `C:\Program Files\Vim`.